# Using Clang with built libstdc++ produces undefined symbol _ZSt15__once_callable

Tags: clang, dynamic-linking, libstdc++

I have built libstdc++ with no modifications yet:

```
cd gccsrcdir/libstdc++-v3/build
../configure --prefix=$PWD/../install
make && make install
```

I am using Ubuntu 21.10 and I set the following environment variables:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=gccsrcdir/libstdc++-v3/install/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=gccsrcdir/libstdc++-v3/install/lib
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=gccsrcdir/libstdc++-v3/install/include/c++/13.0.0
```

When I then use the system's GCC, I get no problems. When I use the system's Clang, it produces a symbol lookup error - even with no parameters:

```
clang++
clang++: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.67: undefined symbol: _ZSt15__once_callable, version GLIBCXX_3.4.11
```

In fact I only need to update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to arrive here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding `-femulated-tls`.

Comment: Thanks, but I had tried that already. It makes no difference.

Comment: Where did you add it? To the compiler flags, right?

Comment: Yes, as in `clang++ -femulated-tls`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol -- `std::__once_callable` is defined in your system `libstdc++.so.6` (it has version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11` in my build, which [means](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) it was added in GCC-4.4.0).

Your build of `libstdc++.so.6` *should* define this symbol as well, but for some reason does not. That *is* a problem -- any binary which uses this symbol will fail at runtime when using your build of `libstdc++.so.6` (which is happening because you've pointed `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to it).

Note: in your case it's the `clang++` binary that is failing to run -- any flags you add to it (such as `-femulated-tls`) are *irrelevant* -- they only affect the binary that would have been generated IF `clang++` itself didn't fail.

---

I just repeated your `configure && make` steps, and the library built this way *also* doesn't define this symbol.

I then repeated the `configure && make`, but starting from top-level GCC directory, and `libstdc++.so.6` built that way *does* define the symbol.

Conclusion: `libstdc++` is configured differently during "normal" GCC build.

The definition comes from `mutex.o`, which is built from `./libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/mutex.cc`, and which has this chunk of code:

```
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS

namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
{
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION

#ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_TLS
  __thread void* __once_callable;
  __thread void (*__once_call)();
...
```

So it sounds like either `_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS` or `_GLIBCXX_HAVE_TLS` is not defined when doing `configure && make` in the `libstdc++-v3` directly.

Digging further, I see that `libstdc++-v3` determines `_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS` by trying to compile `#include "gthr.h"`, and that file is available in `libgcc/gthr.h`, but *not* in "standard" installed GCC.

```
../libstdc++-v3/configure && grep _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS config.h
/* #undef _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS */
```

TL;DR: correctly configuring `libstdc++.so` is complicated, and you will be better off building *complete* GCC.

Once you have a complete build, you will have a `libstdc++-v3` directory properly configured, and can just rebuilt in that directory:

```
grep _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS  ./x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/config.h
#define _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS 1
```

Comment: Many thanks, I'll run that through when I get a chance.

Comment: After you say "...can just rebuilt in that directory:" I was expecting something like `make libstdc++-v3`, but instead you suggest to invoke `grep` and then list a `#define`. Everything until then reads clearly, but I can't follow that last part.

Comment: @user2023370 The `grep` simply confirms the "properly configured" part. After doing full build, you can modify/rebuild just in the `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3` directory and wouldn't have to rebuild the rest of GCC.

Comment: Yes, of course: the second line is the output of the first line.